# Android O use hide api

Tags: android

Well ,I am an aosp android developer, So I develop apps that in AOSP environment.

But when update to O version , all system method that has @hide in comment I can't use anymore . But this will not happen in android N version .

Is there any blog or release note for this change ?

PS:such as this method :
TelephonyManager.from(Context context)

Comment: You can find [android O behavior changes on developer page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

Comment: I have already read this website ,but unfortunate , there is no information about this change.